# Label Triangle with text in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I want to create a label with the triangle shape for cardview as displayed in below image. Is there a way that I can specify a triangle shape in an xml file OR can I achieve it easily with any other way?

[image]

Comment: use background image

Comment: @AmitVaghela : Can I do it with XML?

Comment: I think you are looking for [TriangleLabelView](https://github.com/shts/TriangleLabelView).

Comment: can anyone tell me reason behind -ve mark ?

Comment: @AmitVaghela : I didn't do it.

Comment: @vrundpurohit : Library is good. I wonder, if we can do it without external library.

Comment: than as @AmitVaghela suggested do it with image.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **android:background** attribute, to set textview like above

Example:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/cal"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textColor="@color/darkslate"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView >
```

Comment: you have to generate image as you want in background of cardview and than use it.

Comment: Thanks @AmitVaghela..I Decided to go with TriangleLabelView library.